# HTML5 storage with no dependency from cookies

Tags: html, persistence, local-storage, storage

We have large set of computers which are available for different users.

We need to identify from which computer user is currently working.

All computers work in different networks. Each network connected to the server via VPN. So, different computers may have the same ip-address and mac-adress.

We tried to use HTML5 storage. Firstly we have configured parameter 'ls.COMP-ID'. But user can clear cookies, therefore clear storage.

Is there any other way to configure computer to identify it on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can configure the computer to disallow it, the user is always going to be able to remove any settings you store at the computer.

But there's other ways of identifying which computer is connecting!

The easiest would be to require the users to log-in before they can access the page, then you can be certain what user is connecting.

Otherwise if the computers aren't all the same, you can create a unique id for the computer based on installed plugins, language, screen resolution (and stored cookies).

But if you're unable to require them to log-in and all the computers look the same, I would just use Mozilla's [localForage](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage) and hope that they don't remove the